# Position absolute in ie7 problems

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, position, css-position

Im having a bit of trouble with ie7(who hasnt)

I want the slide thats currently below the 3 content divs to be visible, and the content to start at the bottom of the slider. as it is in the other browsers and verions.
but i cannot get it to work in internet explorer 7... its like it doesnt know the height of the element, this works in every other major browser though including ie 8, 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have define the `position absolute` cordinates

like this

```
#Slider {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 210px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, nice tip.. But it doesnt help me with my problem

Comment: when you give a element an absolute position then the other elements not consider his height & width for this you can use position:relative instead of position:absolute or you can give a that positon:absolute element inside  a position:relative element.

Comment: Put it in a position:relative; container solved the problem! Thank you!